# Where should I put my global constants in a .NET library?

Tags: vb.net, constants

I'm working with an API that spits out a lot of data in name=value format. At first I processed everything by doing simple string comparisons:

```
Sub ProcessData(ByVal name As String, ByVal value As String)
    If name = "thisname" Then
        DoThis(value)
    ElseIf name = "thatname" Then
        DoThat(value)
    End If
End Sub
```

But with over 20 different possible names to process, this quickly became hard to maintain. My next step was to move the strings over to constants defined in a private sub-class:

```
 Private Class Parameters
     Private Sub New()
     End Sub

     Public Const ThisName As String = "thisname"
     Public Const ThatName As String = "thatname"

 End Class
```

And my method would look like this:

```
    Sub ProcessData(ByVal name As String, ByVal value As String)
        If name = Parameters.ThisName Then
            DoThis(value)
        ElseIf name = Parameters.ThatName Then
            DoThat(value)
        End If
    End Sub
```

This was already a huge leap forward, but now I find myself in a position where I need to be able to use these constants in other classes. I'm hesitant about moving them to a global class, but I just don't see another option.

Where do global constants go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are constants. This means that no one can change their value.
You should ask yourself what these constants represent.
If they are pieces of global information needed everywhere in your program then there is no objection to put them in a global shared class.
For a better understanding of their meaning I will comment them with XML comments and go ahead with coding.

Comment: They are definitely pieces that I need in more than one place, but in my opinion moving them away mainly just makes it harder to get an understanding of what the constants are used for. You would actually have to search for references on each shared class to see where the pieces belong to, right?

Comment: @StevenDotNet No doubt, but you are already there (I mean, you need to manage complexity). You need to have a well organized code. For example, all the constants required from more classes may be in a single file with other global stuff. (Kind of Application.Core.dll)

Answer (score 5):

Constants should be Private or Friend.  The failure mode is that their values get compiled into the IL.  So if you create a bug fix for one assembly and change a public constant then *other* assemblies that use your updated one still use the old values.  Very nasty failure mode.

If you need a Public constant value then you should use the ReadOnly keyword.

Comment: Following this mindset, why would you ever use a constant over a Readonly Shared variable?

Comment: They are cheaper, they don't take space in the loader heap.  Which is the problem.